# Meta key in Terminal.app vs national characters

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal.app

I'm using Terminal.app, and I'd like to use emacs running inside - either locally, or after sshing to remote server. Problem is, I can't get working `Meta` modifier.

Namely, if I enable 'Use option as meta key', `Option` key works like proper `Meta`, but I lose ability to enter Polish diacritics (ąęłóśźńżć), that are entered with right `Option`.

If I disable 'Use option as meta key', my `Meta` is gone, but I can again use Polish characters. In this state they appear only with right `Option` modifier, so I guess it's Terminal.app's fault that it doesn't make a difference between left and right `Option` key, when the relevant preference is selected.

What are my options then? Is there a good solution for my problem? I can always use `ESC` as a poor man's `Meta` replacement, but I don't like that idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: iTerm got two major versions since my patch, and this functionality is now built in.

OK, I got annoyed enough and wrote an iTerm patch, that allows me to do what I want: left Option is Meta, right Option is national characters modifier. You can find the patch, binary and the rest of the story [here](http://swissarmyhammer.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/osx-terminal-meta-key-national-characters/)

Comment: Your link doesn’t appear to work any more. :(

Comment: Ah, I see this feature is in the latest version. Shweeet. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be better remapping the ever-useless capslock to meta? Fairly standard redo for *nix versions of emacs, but you will have to do an iTerm patch, probably.

Comment: Capslock is already Control :)